# Obtener un campo específico de una tabla y asignarlo automáticamente como llave foránea en otra tabla con Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual registra eventos y el artefacto que se pudiera dar en cada evento.
Hasta ahorita ya tengo mis modelos "Listos" y ya se pueden guardar, modificar y eliminar eventos, también se puede escoger la llave foránea que relaciona al **entregable** con el **evento**, sin embargo, se necesita que se asigne automáticamente. ¿Y como hago esto?

[image: Imagen de la tabla evetnos]

En esta tabla de eventos, donde dice **entregable**, seleccionar donde dice añadir y que guarde el nombre del evento, para después de llenar el formulario de **añadir** y después guardarlo.

Modelo de eventos:

```
class   eventos(models.Model):
    no_Evento   =   models.AutoField(primary_key=True)#LLAVE_PRIMARIA
    titulo      =   models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Título',)
    descripcion =   models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Descripción')
    fecha       =   models.DateField()
    calificacion=   models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Calificacion',    null=True)
    comentarios =   models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Comentarios',    null=True)
    presupuesto =   models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Presupuesto', max_digits=10,   decimal_places=2)
    total_Gastos=   models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Total Gastos',    max_digits=10,   decimal_places=2,    null=True)
    planeadas   =   models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Planeadas')
    real        =   models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Reales',    null=True)
    entregadas  =   models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Entregadas',    null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.titulo
```

Modelo de entregables:

```
class   entregable(models.Model):
    id_Ent      =   models.AutoField(primary_key=True)#LLAVE_PRIMARIA
    descripcion =   models.TextField(max_length=50)
    precio      =   models.IntegerField()#SMALL_MONEY
    no_evento   =   models.OneToOneField(eventos,   on_delete=models.CASCADE,   null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Número de entregable {self.id_Ent},  Titutlo de evento: {self.no_evento}'
```

Vista de los eventos.

```
def crearEvento(request):
    form    =   evento_crear_F()

    if  request.method  ==  'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form    =   evento_crear_F(request.POST)
        print(form.errors)
        if  form.is_valid():
            print('salvado')
            form.save()
            return  redirect('index')
        else:
            print('no salvado   ')

    context =   {'form':form}
    return  render(request,'RUTA', context)
```

Vista de los entregables:

```
def crearEntregable(request):

    fomr_crear_ent  =   entregable_crear_F()

    if  request.method  ==  'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        fomr_crear_ent  =   entregable_crear_F()
        print(fomr_crear_ent.errors)
        if  fomr_crear_ent.is_valid():
            instance    =   fomr_crear_ent.save(commit=False)
            instance.no_evento  =   request.id_Ent    
            instance.save()
            print('salvado')
            return  redirect('index')
        else:
            print('no salvado')
    context =   {'fomr_crear_ent':fomr_crear_ent}
    return  render(request, 'RUTA',    context)
```

Y este es el campo de el botón en el HTML.

```
<td>
    <div  class="centrar-texto  margin__g">
         <a  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{%  url 'crearEntregable'%}">Añadir</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

El programa está siendo desarrollado en Django 4.0.6

Estoy desarrollando un código con ApiView, pero si se puede de forma normal mediante Django, sería mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Me manejo mejor utilizando "Class Based Views", pero ahí va una posible solución:

En tu formulario `entregable_crear_F` podrías hacer referencia al evento utilizando un campo `hidden`. Por ejemplo:

```
class EntregableCrearF(model.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'no_evento': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

De esta manera aceptarás que haya un campo `hidden` que haga referencia al evento.

Una vez hecho esto, puedes incluir este campo por defecto en el momento de cargar el formulario en la pantalla de crear el entregable. Sería algo así:

```
def crearEntregable(request):

    fomr_crear_ent  =   entregable_crear_F(initial={'evento': request.id_Ent}) 

    if  request.method  ==  'POST':
        ...

    context =   {'fomr_crear_ent':fomr_crear_ent}
    return  render(request, 'RUTA',    context)
```

Si haces esto, al guardar ya se estará guardando el evento. O debería :-P